# How to get all 99 or more sections in a notebook via GET sections OneNote API

Tags: onenote

I tried GET sections API to get all 99 or more sections in a notebook.
However, I got error response that status code was 500.
Is this a bug or a feature?

My request URL was as follows.

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/{my notebook id}/sections

* The notebook has 99 or more sections.
```

The error response JSON was as follows.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "An error has occurred."
  }
}
```

What's the way to get all 99 or more sections in a notebook via GET sections API?

Comment: You are doing it right. That's the correct URL.  Can you ping me at garethj@microsoft.com and send me the x-CorrelationId header from one of those requests please, and we can see if it is a bug.

Comment: I sent the x-CorrelationId to above E-mail address. Please see if this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the OneNote service which has since been fixed in production.

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct calling pattern, regardless of the number of sections, so it looks like a system problem of some kind that we'll need to track down.